# Breakpoint shortcut key in Vim Python-mode not updating

Tags: vim, python-mode

I installed Python-mode as a plugin in my .vimrc:

`Plugin 'klen/python-mode'`

It got installed fine, but I had the breakpoint set to my `<leader>b` like this:

```
" Enable breakpoints plugin
let g:pymode_breakpoint = 1
let g:pymode_breakpoint_key = '<leader>b'
```

I then wanted to change the `'<leader>b'` to `'<leader>k'`, but when I make the change, I still get the breakpoint when I hit `leader-b` and nothing when I do `leader-k`.

I've tried running `PluginInstall`, restarting Vim, and restarting my terminal. How do I get Vim to recognize this change to the .vimrc?

Comment: what python version are you using? Does it correctly detect the debugger?

For me this breakpoints dont work at all. I am using python 3.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `g:pymode_breakpoint_key` is not the name of the option.  According to the [pymode docs](https://github.com/klen/python-mode/blob/develop/doc/pymode.txt#L248), the option is `g:pymode_breakpoint_bind`.  So the below should work:

```
let g:pymode_breakpoint_bind = '<leader>k'
```